# Find duplicate items in the specific column and update the item which has MIN row number with '-'

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Data Looks like this:

```
RN    StartTime                StopTime                Activity

1    2013-02-03 12:07:39       2013-02-03 14:58:13     A1
2    2013-02-03 16:00:02       2013-02-04 04:25:32     A2
3    2013-02-04 04:25:32       2013-02-04 04:25:32     A2
4    2013-02-04 05:31:32       2013-02-04 05:57:32     A3
5    2013-02-04 06:24:32       2013-02-04 06:54:32     A4
```

The **StartTime** in row 3 and the **StopTime** in row 2 & 3 is similar.
I would like to Format it something like this:

```
RN    StartTime                StopTime                Activity

1    2013-02-03 12:07:39       2013-02-03 14:58:13     A1
2    2013-02-03 16:00:02       -                       A2
3    -                         2013-02-04 04:25:32     A2
4    2013-02-04 05:31:32       2013-02-04 05:57:32     A3
5    2013-02-04 06:24:32       2013-02-04 06:54:32     A4
```

The **StartTime** problem is solved using CASE statement, but I need to find the duplicate in **StopTime** and update the the one with smaller RN with '-'.

**Note: Activity is always going to be same for duplicates.**

This is my query:

```
SELECT CTE.RN,
(CASE
  WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartTime, 120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, StopTime, 120)
    THEN '-'
  ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartTime, 120)
  END) As StartTime, StopTime
FROM CTE
ORDER BY StopTime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CTE.RN,
(CASE
  WHEN c1.StartTime = c1.StopTime
    THEN '-'
  ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, c1.StartTime, 120)
  END) As StartTime, 
  CASE WHEN c1.StopTime = c2.StartTime THEN '-' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, c1.StopTime, 120) END AS StopTime
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE c2   
   ON c2.RN = c1.RN + 1
ORDER BY c1.StopTime
```

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that the value you want to compare on to generate the appropriate '-' in the stop time column is obtained by looking forward one row. You can do that by using a join with the right criteria... if it works to use RN+1, you can JOIN the table to itself where a.RN+1 = b.RN.  Then, you will be able to CASE on a.StopTime = b.StartTime to determine whether or not you should use the '-'.

```
SELECT a.RN
      ,CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.StartTime,120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.StopTime,120)
            THEN '-'
       ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.StartTime,120)
       END StartTime
      ,CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.StopTime,120) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,b.StartTime,120)
            THEN '-'
       ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.StopTime,120)
       END StopTime
  FROM CTE a
  LEFT JOIN CTE b on a.RN+1 = b.RN
```